# Replacing negative values in specific columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

This is driving me crazy! I want to replace all negative values in columns containing string "_p" with the value multiplied by -0.5. Here is the code, where `Tdf` is a dataframe.

```
    L=list(Tdf.filter(regex='_p').columns)
    Tdf[L]=Tdf[L].astype(float)
    Tdf[Tdf[L]<0]= Tdf[Tdf[L]<0]*-.5
```

I get the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value"

I variefied that all columns in `Tdf[L]` are type float64.

Even more confusing is that when I run a code, essentially the same except looping through multiple dataframes, it works:

```
csv_names=['Full','Missing','MinusMissing']

for DF in csv_names:
    L=list(vars()[DF].iloc[:,1:])
    vars()[DF][L]=vars()[DF][L].astype(float)
    vars()[DF][vars()[DF][L]<0]= vars()[DF][vars()[DF][L]<0]*-.5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't understand the description of the problem. If the value contains a string `_p`, then it is a string, correct? How should the code multiply that value by 0.5? What should the result be, and according to what logic?

Comment: I want to work only on columns with "_p" in the name of the column.  The columns with "_p" in the name are of type float64.  I want to multiple the negative values in these columns by -.05.  Essentially, making all negative values positive and half the absolute value of the original.

Comment: Oh, the `_p` is in the *name*, I see. So the next question is, what happens when you try to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem yourself, walking through the logic carefully? At what point does the code behaviour diverge from what you expect? For example, does `L` have the value you expect? Does `Tdf[L]`? Does `Tdf[Tdf[L]<0]`? Did you try making a separate Dataframe with only the filtered columns? Does the code work if you take that approach?

Comment: "Even more confusing is that when I run a code, essentially the same except looping through multiple dataframes, it works" It looks as if this version of the code does not do any filtering.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your error. Can you please provide a working example?

Comment: Gah.  Okay.  In the second example I did not use the `.filter` because I only needed to ignore the first column. I did that by using `.iloc[:,1:]`.  But you are correct in that the filtering is where it is breaking.  If use `.iloc[:,2:]` instead, the code does not work.  Similarly, if I create a new Dataframe with only the filtered columns, the code works.  I'm pretty new to python, as you can tell, so I'm a bit stuck on how to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify your question. If your question is about the error,

```
Tdf[Tdf[L]<0]= Tdf[Tdf[L]<0]*-.5
```

likely fails to non np.nan null values, as the error describes.

If your question is instead:"How do I multiply negative values by -0.5 in columns with "_p" in the column name?"

```
for col in Tdf.filter(regex='_p').columns.tolist():
    Tdf[col] = Tdf.apply((lambda Tdf: Tdf[col]*-.5 if Tdf[col] < 0 else Tdf[col], axis =1)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the for loop.  That does fix my problem.  But I am still really confused as to why I can't get the first statement working.

Comment: Indeed! Sorry but I don't think I can replicate it without your data. Do you have null values in the data? Can they be filled with 0 or mean/mode values? That may fix the issue in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: You just need to filter out the string column which is type object. And then work on the data that is left. You can disable the slice warning if you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


Tdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name", "a_p", "b_p", "c"],
                   data=[["a", -1, -2, -3],
                         ["b", 1, -2, 3],
                         ["c", 1, np.NaN, 3]])

# get only non object columns
sub_Tdf = Tdf.select_dtypes(exclude='object')

# then work on slice
L = list(sub_Tdf.filter(regex='_p').columns)
sub_Tdf[L] = sub_Tdf[L].astype(float)
sub_Tdf[sub_Tdf[L] < 0] = sub_Tdf[sub_Tdf[L] < 0] * -.5

# see results were applied correctly
print(Tdf)
```

Output:

```
  name  a_p  b_p  c
0    a   -1 -2.0 -3
1    b    1 -2.0  3
2    c    1  NaN  3
```

This will trigger the setting value on slice warning. You can disable it with.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: I get the error when my dataframe has a column of strings.  Even if that column does not have a "_p" in the name.  for example, add a addition column to the above dataframe makes the code fail.... 
````Tdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=["name","a_p", "b_p", "c"], data=[["a",-1,-2,-3],                                           ["b",1,-2,3],["c",1,np.NaN,3]] )````